# How do I replicate the searchbox in Chrome's new tab page?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

[image]

I am creating my own new tab page and want to include the google search box. I notice that in the current version of chrome when you start typing in the input it auto-focus' the omnibox in the browser.

Im wondering how to do this in my own new tab extension?

Comment: It's using [embeddedsearch API](https://www.chromium.org/embeddedsearch) which is probably only available for the built-in new tab page. Note, this input box will be soon replaced by a normally behaving search input box, see https://crbug.com/243926 and try it in Canary after enabling `chrome://flags/#ntp-realbox` flag.

Comment: @wOxxOm ah damn :( Thats a shame